# Google Maps error with Circle when passed a valid lat/lng for center

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm getting an error about the lat not being a valid value - when I pass the "center" to a `Marker` it works fine, it's the center of the map, the only thing it's not working with is the `Circle`...

The error:

`InvalidValueError: at index 0: at index 0: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral with finite coordinates: in property lat: NaN is not an accepted value`

The code:

```js
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    this.$data.myMap = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv as HTMLElement, {
      center: { lat: this.$props.circle.lat, lng: this.$props.circle.lng },
      zoom: 12,
    });
    const center = { lat: this.$data.myMap.center.lat(), lng: this.$data.myMap.center.lng() };
    console.log('Center', center);
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: center,
      map: this.$data.myMap,
    });
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    this.$data.myCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: this.$data.myMap,
      center,
      radius: this.$props.circle.radius * 100,
    });
```

The console.log message:

```
Center {lat: 37.7674915, lng: -122.4450328}

js?key=...&libraries=places&v=weekly:78 InvalidValueError: at index 0: at index 0: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral with finite coordinates: in property lat: NaN is not an accepted value
...
```

As you can see, the only error is when we create the circle - the map draws with the correct center and the marker is placed. What is the deal here?

EDIT:

Even if I hard-code center I get the same error - this does not work:

```
this.$data.myCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: this.$data.myMap,
      center: { lat: 37.7674915, lng: -122.4450328 },
      radius: this.$props.circle.radius * 100,
    });
```

This does not work either:

```
this.$data.myCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: this.$data.myMap,
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.7674915, -122.4450328),
      radius: this.$props.circle.radius * 100,
    });
```

Here you can see the map & marker work properly:

[image: Google Map]

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the error?  There is an obvious syntax error in the first piece of code in your question (`center,` should be `center: center,`).

Comment: @geocodezip - that's not a typo - it's valid ES6 syntax... The code is all valid ES6 that's getting transpiled.

Comment: @geocodezip - It's a bad error message from Google, the real issue was the `radius`

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out the error message is what is wrong.

The error was with the radius, and not the `center` of the circle. Anyone that's getting this error make sure to check the radius as well as the circle lat/lng attributes.